# ImportXML function in Google Sheets #ERROR

Tags: xml, google-sheets

Have often frequented these pages but never needed to raise a new question...

I've searched high and low for a solution to, what should be, a fairly simple ImportXML function in Google sheets and I simply cannot grab the data I'm looking for.

Companies House in the UK make their basic company data freely available in various formats. For example, for company number 06732413 (I've picked that entirely at random as a usable example), their data can be accessed at http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/06732413 (or alternatively at http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/06732413.xml, and a range of other types.)

I simply cannot find a way for ImportXML to return a specific element within that data, say the `<Accounts>/<NextDueDate>` data.

Is there an obvious solution?

Comment: Which data point are you trying to pull in? Its helpful to know if/why any edge case is preventing it'

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=index(importxml("http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/06732413","//*[3]/td"),3,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a format for csv you can just use this function to pull it in:

`=importdata("http://data.companieshouse.gov.uk/doc/company/06732413.csv")`

note you just append `.csv` onto the end of the url for it to work.